# Can’t group my text into blocks of 5 letters in VB2010

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I'm relatively new to VB and I am trying to develop a simple Encryption Program.  I have most of the code nailed but to make my encryption program even better I want to group my text into blocks of 5 letters.  However, my Function to do this doesn’t work. I suspect something is wrong with my IFs or loop.

```
    Function ExtendedEncrypt(ByVal MessageText As String, ByVal txtOffset As Integer) As String
            Dim StringLength As String
    Dim CharToEncrypt As Char
    Dim EncryptedText As String
    Dim CharAscNumber As Integer
    Dim CipherText As String
    Dim Counter As Integer
    StringLength = Len(MessageText)
    CipherText = ""
    For Counter = 1 To StringLength
        CharToEncrypt = Mid(MessageText, Counter, 1)
        If CharToEncrypt = " " Then
            EncryptedText = ""
        Else : CharAscNumber = Asc(CharToEncrypt)
            CharAscNumber = CharAscNumber + txtOffset
            If CharAscNumber > 126 Then
                CharAscNumber = CharAscNumber - 94
            End If
            EncryptedText = Chr(CharAscNumber)
            If Counter Mod 5 = 1 And Counter > 1 Then EncryptedText = EncryptedText & " "
        End If
        CipherText = CipherText & EncryptedText
        txtEncrypted.Text = CipherText
    Next
    Return CipherText
End Function
```

Comment: What did you get in result?

Comment: Your iteration variable is `SpaceCounter` and you tamper with this variable within the loop. I guess that's not what you wanted. Consider using a separate iteration variable.

Comment: Many, many thanks for your feedback - I really appreciate it. I have tried to add a second iteration variable (see edited code) but this is not working either.  I'm not getting any syntax or run time errors so I guess its another flaw in my logic.  Can you please help me identify where I have gone wrong?

Comment: What line is it failing on? See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't need `SpaceCounter`. Get rid of everything relating to that. As long as you don't touch the counter, you're fine. Just do the following: `If Counter Mod 5 = 0 And Counter > 1 Then EncryptedText = EncryptedText & " "`
- Next, you are passing the function a string 'MessageText', but referencing a control `txtMessage`. Change all references to`txtMessage.text` to `MessageText`.
- Remove references to other controls. `txtEncrypted.Text = CipherText` should not be needed.

**Final Recommended Result (you can remove comments i.e 'texttext)**

```
Function ExtendedEncrypt(ByVal MessageText As String, ByVal txtOffset As Integer) As String
  'Removed a bunch of unnecessary variables
  Dim CipherText As String
  Dim CharAscNumber As Integer
  Dim Counter As Integer

  'Condensed this section down. Removed/replaced references to EncryptedText
  For Counter = 1 To Len(MessageText)
    CharAscNumber = Asc(Mid(MessageText, Counter, 1)) + txtOffset '+Counter (optional, remember to account for this in decryption)
    If CharAscNumber > 126 Then CharAscNumber = CharAscNumber - 94 'Consider -126

    CipherText = CipherText & Chr(CharAscNumber)
    If Counter Mod 5 = 0 And Counter > 1 Then CipherText = CipherText & " "
  Next
  Return CipherText
End Function
```

Using this "We go to the park" with Offset 23 returns "n|7~( 7-(7- !|7)x +$".

Comment: Wow, that was quick. I am very grateful, will try implementing your suggestions. Thank you so much

Comment: Currently, the way the code plays out, you keep spaces from original text and don't increment the counter. This will cause odd shaped text chunks. For instance, "We go to the park" will look like "XX XX X X XXX X XXX". Consider encrypting spaces the same way as all the other text.

Comment: Ok, so I've got rid of SpaceCounter, added the IF you suggested and tried to remove spaces from the original text. (See new script above) However, this does give me some odd shaped chunks rather than groups of five as you have predicted. As a newbie, I'm struggling to implement you last suggestion (I'm ashamed to admit that what I have now has taken practically forever to write and a fair bit of research). Would you please elaborate with a code snippet?

Comment: Warning, this `If CharAscNumber > 126 Then CharAscNumber = CharAscNumber - 94` code may make it difficult to decode later. You may want to subtract by 126.

Comment: Also, you can try adding the letter position to the asc values to make repeat letters different resulting characters. Should be easy enough to decode.

Comment: You're welcome! Please pick my answer so this question will appear resolved.